# Add a value to each cell in the column

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to modify a specific table in the database by adding a value to each cell in the table. I am currently using this code

```
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("UPDATE ImportProduct_Add_Item SET home_delivery_fees = @home_delivery_fees,
                                                                     additon_customs_fees_egp = @additon_customs_fees_egp,
                                                                     customs_fees_egp = @customs_fees_egp,
                                                                     shipping_fees = @shipping_fees,
                                                                     usd_shipping_fees = @usd_shipping_fees,
                                                                     egp_shipping_fees = @egp_shipping_fees ", sqlconn)

    command.Parameters.Add("@home_delivery_fees", SqlDbType.Money).Value = (Val(TextBox22.Text) / Val(TextBox8.Text))
    command.Parameters.Add("@additon_customs_fees_egp", SqlDbType.Money).Value = (Val(TextBox25.Text) / Val(TextBox8.Text))
    command.Parameters.Add("@customs_fees_egp", SqlDbType.Money).Value = (Val(TextBox26.Text) / Val(TextBox8.Text))
    command.Parameters.Add("@shipping_fees", SqlDbType.Money).Value = (Val(TextBox23.Text) / Val(TextBox8.Text))
    command.Parameters.Add("@usd_shipping_fees", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CheckBox1.CheckState
        command.Parameters.Add("@egp_shipping_fees", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CheckBox2.CheckState
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Done")
```

What I want is to multiply the output in a column and let the name of this column is "total_product_price_egp"

To be as follows

```
command.Parameters.Add("@shipping_fees", SqlDbType.Money).Value = (Val(TextBox23.Text) / Val(TextBox8.Text)) * total_product_price_egp
```

Comment: Have you not noticed that you are referring to database columns in the SQL code?  If you want to multiply a value by the value of a database column, where do you think that should be done?

Comment: where is `total_product_price_egp` column, what is the value of this column. Review your code once again. `What I want is to multiply the output in a column` what is output in your query. You wrote a query to update there is no output.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not completely clear but based on a couple of assumptions.

1. total_product_price_egp is a database field
2. The field that you want to update is shipping_fees

change your code to the following:

```
Dim command As New SqlCommand("UPDATE ImportProduct_Add_Item SET 
    home_delivery_fees = @home_delivery_fees,
    additon_customs_fees_egp = @additon_customs_fees_egp,
    customs_fees_egp = @customs_fees_egp,
    shipping_fees = @shipping_fees * total_product_price_egp,
    usd_shipping_fees = @usd_shipping_fees,
    egp_shipping_fees = @egp_shipping_fees ", sqlconn)

command.Parameters.Add("@home_delivery_fees", SqlDbType.Money).Value = (Val(TextBox22.Text) / Val(TextBox8.Text))
command.Parameters.Add("@additon_customs_fees_egp", SqlDbType.Money).Value = (Val(TextBox25.Text) / Val(TextBox8.Text))
command.Parameters.Add("@customs_fees_egp", SqlDbType.Money).Value = (Val(TextBox26.Text) / Val(TextBox8.Text))
command.Parameters.Add("@shipping_fees", SqlDbType.Money).Value = (Val(TextBox23.Text) / Val(TextBox8.Text))
command.Parameters.Add("@usd_shipping_fees", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CheckBox1.CheckState
command.Parameters.Add("@egp_shipping_fees", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CheckBox2.CheckState
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Done")
```